# EOF reading C/C++

Tags: c, getchar

I'm using NetBeans MinGW to compile simple c programs(I'm new at this). 
My problem is that I have this simple code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int c,i=0;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        i++;
    }
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

and when I try to end input like this:

> hello^Z [enter]

it doesn't do it, I need to re-enter

> ^Z[enter]

to end it.

I'd appreciate that you tell me why this happens.

Thanks in advance

Comment: print `c` inside `while` loop and see what will print when you hit ctrl + z for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

C input is line-oriented by default.  Ending a line with the EOF character (`^Z` on Windows, `^D` on Unix) ends the line (without a trailing newline) but doesn't actually signal end of file; the end of file condition is signaled when it's encountered on the next read, i.e. at the beginning of a line.

Comment: I don't think it is a language specific, but the way the console interprets user input.

Comment: is this applicable for linux? it works for first ctrl + D(gnome-terminal).

Comment: @John: if you are in the middle of a line and you press `^D`, it sends the partial line but doesn't EOF.  Press it a second time and it's taken as EOF.  (This is in `icanon` mode.)

Comment: but i pressed once.it worked.i think,when no more character to flush, ctrl + D sends EOF too. is it correct?

Comment: @John:  Yes.  I did test that before saying it; `hello^D` typed to `cat` caused it to echo back `hello` (without a newline) but it continued to wait for input; a second `^D` caused it to exit.

Answer (score 1):

Just the way the console handles input

Ctrl-Z on a UNIX system would be an interrupt to let you suspend the process, so I guess it is a Windows console.

When you Ctrl-Z after the characters it probably does treat this as an "End" which is Ctrl-Z on its own.

Comment: yes. Ctrl + D for linux. Also MinGW means `Minimalist GNU for Windows`